# What's up with spacing and syntax errors in Shell Scripts?

Tags: shell

I'm pretty familiar and comfortable with Batch Scripts on Windows.
I've only just started out on UNIX and I'm having a hard time getting the hang of spacing things properly.

The script below works fine. Let's call it **script1.sh**

```
!#/bin/sh
now=$(date +"%s")
echo "This file was created on $now"
```

This script pasted below however throws up an error ,also which I've pasted further below

```
!#/bin/sh
now=$(date + "%s")
echo "This file was created on $now"
```

> ```
> [root@localhost /]# sh postbackup.sh
> postbackup.sh: line 1: !#/bin/sh: No such file or directory
> date: extra operand `%s'
> Try `date --help' for more information.
> This file was created on
> ```

Why does the space between + and "%s" matter ? Additional information on how this might affect in other cases would be extremely helpful.

Comment: well actually on my CentOS Machine !# works. :)

Comment: Actually, on your CentOS machine, `!#` causes an error that does not cause the script to exist, when you run it as an argument to `sh`.  But that character combination will *not* identify the shell interpreter that should be used for the script.  Make the script executable and run it from csh/tcsh, and you'll see much more profound failures.

Comment: Since you're familiar with DOS batch programming, consider this.  You often put `@echo off` as the first line, but if instead you put `*echo off`, your script may still run, but it will behave differently because that first command was incorrect.  Same thing here.  The incorrect "shebang" notation makes your script behave differently in certain situations, even if you're not seeing them yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors in your script:

---

> postbackup.sh: line 1: !#/bin/sh: No such file or directory

This is because you should use `!#` (wrong), and not `#!` (correct), and it tries to run the `!#/bin/sh` command, which doesn't exist.
This error is otherwise fairly harmless and it "works" because you call `sh` explicitly with `sh postbackup.sh`, but it's still an error and you should fix it.

---

> date: extra operand `%s'

This also doesn't work on the commandline, `date` expects a single argument, which starts with `+`, and then provides you a format (`%s` in this case), adding a space there makes it *two* arguments, and `date` doesn't know that the `%s` belongs to the `+`.

As I said, this will also fail if you enter it on the command line:

```
$ date + %s  
date: extra operand ‘%s’
```

So what you need to do, is make this a single argument, which can be done either by adding quotes, or escaping the space with a  `\`:

```
$ date '+ %s'
 1427897164
$ date +\ %s
 1427897164
```

Note that the output now starts with a space! This is expected, as you've given a space to `date`.

As far as I know, there is no way to prevent this leading space, except removing it later ... I would suggest that you just don't use a space here ;-)

Comment: Using `./postbackup.sh` will work actually as the current shell will execute the script directly in most circumstances. That isn't great to depend on and will cause problems if the current shell and the desired shell are the same though.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of a shell script is in the format:

```
#!/path/to/shell
```

The notation here is important.  It starts with a `#` because that character is used to denote a *comment* normally in a script. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This is a comment about the following line, which prints a greeting.
echo "Hello."
```

Commenting your code is often a good idea, especially as things get bigger and more complex.

The reason this is significant is that if you run, say, `sh script1.sh`, and the script starts with a comment, the comment will not generate an error.  There is a special case, however, if the *first line* of a script is a comment that has an exclamation point.  This notation is called "shell magic" or "shebang" (or perhaps some other names too), and is used by shells to determine what interpreter to use for the rest of the file.  For example, you could use awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { print "This is an awk script."; }
```

By starting the shebang with a comment character, you avoid errors when the script is run as an argument to the shell (as in, `sh script1.sh`).

Now you know WHY you got that error.

The issue with "date" is that its usage wants a single "string" as an argument, and the shell will use whitespace to separate arguments.  I usually solve this by making sure I put the leading `+` inside a quoted string:

```
$ date '+%Y-%m-%d'
```

Note that this formatting string is usually the *last* argument provided to the `date` command.  Other arguments would depend on the operating system you're in.  For example, if you wanted the date of an epoch second in Linux, you'd use:

```
$ date -d @1420898113 '+%Y-%m-%d'
```

Note that whitespace delimits arguments here too.  If you put a space between the + and the format string without quotes of course), you'd make that into two arguments, which is not what the `date` command expects.